# How to create dynamic object members that are able to reference enclosed variables/functions?

Tags: javascript, com, closures, msscriptcontrol

How would I go about creating a dynamic object in such a way that it is wrapped in a closure and then, later on, be able to add members to the object that are able to reference the enclosed variables?

As this example shows, `test.myFunct()` can not reference the enclosed `example` variable:

```
var example = "from global";
(function (global) {
    var example = "from closure";
    global.test = {};
}(this));

test.myFunct = fnction () { return example; };
test.myFunct(); // "from global"
```

So I tried creating an adder function, hoping to solve the issue, but to no avail:

```
var example = "from global";
(function (global) {
    var example = "from closure";
    global.test = {
        add: function (name, value) { global.mJSON[name] = value; }
    }
}(this));

test.add("myFunct", function () { return example; });
test.myFunct(); // "from global"
```

Is there a way to dynamically add members to an object, later in runtime, that can reference enclosed members?

**Why It's Needed**:

I'm working with [mIRC's](http://www.mirc.com) COM implementation to access `MSScriptControl.ScriptControl`'s jScript engine. Due to a limitation with using mIRC, I'm limited to ~4k bytes per command execution from mIRC. As such, I need to break my JS file down into chunks of ~3500 bytes or smaller before calling the `ScriptControl`'s `AddCode`, `ExecuteStatement`, or `Eval` methods.

**Notes**:

I'd rather not have to use static "helper" functions that return values of the variables/functions enclosed.

Comment: Why do you try to enclose them in a closure instead of simply making them public properties when you want to have them accessible to arbitrary functions?

Comment: My plan was/is to have a wrapper function, that digests the arguments, and then return a dynamic object dependent on the those digested arguments.

Comment: How would you use that? Where do you need this?

Comment: I'm working with [mIRC's](http://www.mirc.com) COM implementation to access MSScriptControl.ScriptControl's jscript engine. Due to a limitation with using mIRC, I'm limited to ~4k bytes per command execution from mIRC. As such I need to break my js file down into chunks of ~3500 bytes or smaller before calling the ScriptControl's AddCode, ExecuteStatement, or Eval methods.

Comment: Omg. So you are ok with dark magic?

Comment: If by 'dark magic' you mean eval, yes, as the eval inputs are not 3rd party sources that need verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to dynamically add members to an object, later in run time, that can reference enclosed members?

No<sup>1</sup>, that would contradict the definition of a (javascript) closure. Just use public properties instead of enclosed variables.

---

1: You could use `eval` to create a new function in the closure scope (from a string) and put it as a member. But that's pure evil:

```
var example = "from global";
(function (exports) {
    var example = "from closure";
    exports.addPrivileged = function(name, args, body) {
        body = arguments[arguments.length-1];
        args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, -1).join(", ");
        this[name] = eval("(function("+args+"){"+body+"})");
        name = args = body = null;
    };
}(test={}));

test.addPrivileged("myFunct", "return example");
console.log(test.myFunct()); // "from closure"
```

Comment: Couple of notes: 'export' is a reserved word causing errors to be thrown, and `test.add(...)` should be `test.addPrivileged(...)`

Comment: @SReject: Of course. I had these fixed when I tried it out, but forgot to copy that back into the post.